# Статус вопросов типа «Что изображено на картинке?»

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

[Символ, изображенный на погоне](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/453762/178412)

На сайте стали часто появляться вопросы, подобные приведенному выше. Как вы считаете, должны ли мы закрывать их? Или они соответствуют тематике сайта?

Полезные материалы:
https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

**А мне интересно, для чего автору это нужно? Словарь составляет?**

А есть ли вообще такие словари? К примеру, Даль  не только давал толкование слов, но иногда попутно объяснял назначение предметов.

Но тогда пусть наш участник форума не хранит *свой словарь*  в секрете, а поделится с нами своими замыслами,  может быть,  люди будут ему помогать охотнее. **Любознательность  приветствуется, если человек интересуется предметом с какой-то целью,  и этим она отличается от праздного любопытства.**

А сейчас наш участник скрытен, неконтактен, в переговоры вступает неохотно, а некоторые ответы просто не замечает, что кажется странным.

Поэтому пока нет желания ему помогать, **а непонятная деятельность может вызывать недоумение.** Может быть, уже существует такой справочник с описанием предметов? Тогда зачем *изобретать велосипед*?

А ответы, которые ему дают участники форума, они-то на чем основаны? Как проверить эту информацию, есть ли ссылки на источники? Чтобы материал **был полезен для ресурса**, он должен быть как-то обоснован, иначе это просто мнение, ничем не подтвержденное.

Также **есть разница** между такими ответами: (1) я бы это назвал (это мое мнение, так у нас называют) и (2) это называется...  Во втором случае было бы нелишне указать источник.

Поэтому имеет смысл  оставить вопросы на форуме только в том случае, если можно **привести их к какой-то норме, учитывая их большое количество.**

Comment: Если есть название, загуглить его является делом нескольких секунд.  А ссылка на источник не всегда уместна. Например информацию по названию водоналивных барьеров я нашёл на сайте по их продаже. Информация вполне достоверна, но давать ссылку на коммерческий источник информации вряд ли стоит, иначе нас такие вопросы и ответы заполонят.

Comment: Все вопросы узкоспециальные, при этом они занимают половину форума, никакой системы я в них не вижу. На какую аудиторию они рассчитаны? Ну вот такой вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453913/Металлическое-изделие-на-стенах-домов Ответ: Металлический кронштейн для флагов.  Для кого эта информация? Для нашего любознательного участника и ещё двух-трех человек, которые читают эти вопросы. Вряд ли кто-нибудь из Сети придет к нам за этим кронштейном. И вот что интересно: вопрос о картинках задал модератор. Это его инициатива или были жалобы?

Comment: А короче говоря, утомляет бесконечный поток однообразных вопросов и картинок, это мое мнение. Хочется чего-нибудь интеллектуального, лингвистического, неоднозначного. А здесь что обсуждать (на форуме)?

Comment: Модератор потому и задал вопрос, что формально правилам эти вопросы соответствуют. а по факту разновидность троллинга. Как единичный вопрос, я считаю такое вполне допустимо, а вот как массовое явление должно пресекаться.

Comment: @МаркИз выразите свое мнение в отдельном ответе, пожалуйста. Я позже то же сделаю. Чтобы был виден перевес в ту или иную сторону. Sharon, спасибо за мнение!

Answer (score 0):

Ну не надо их закрывать! Хорошие ж вопросы! И аккурат по русскому языку,

потому что

картинка-фото заменяет мучительный и многословный процесс описания того, имени чего не знает вопрошатель,

типо:

*"Как называются такие штуковинки, чаще деревянные, но иногда и пластмассовые, но не обязательно, ну вроде колышков, но не колышки, которыми со всех сторон подпирают саженец, но не всегда со всех и не всегда саженец, ну как же это (?), из нашего русского быта-обихода, называется-то?!"*

Comment: Вопросы типа "Как называется вещь на фото" желательно с описанием, где эта вещь встречается) более чем допустимы. А вопросы, что означает тот или иной символ - это уже не лингвистика, а геральдика. Здесь непонятно, чего хочет автор, поэтому вопрос плохой.

Comment: Марк, геральдические символы тоже как-то по-русски называются. Речь об *имени* изображённого. Так хай живэ вопрос!

Comment: С точки зрения русского языка там изображена пятиконечная звезда в обрамлении пшеничных колосьев. Почему это там изображено, что означает и где этот символ ещё используется к русскому языку уже не относится.

Comment: Согласна, русский ограничивается *как называется*. "Почему это там изображено, что означает и где этот символ ещё используется" - нерусский, нерусскоязычный.

Answer (score 0):

Вопросы как называется с изображением этого объекта думаю вполне допустимы и могут быть интересны. Также очень интересными могут быть вопросы со скринами книг, например [этот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20447/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85).

Проблема возникает лишь тогда, когда появляется много однотипных вопросов, и не важно на какую они тему. Даже если эти вопросы будут только по пунктуации, только по орфоэпии, только по орфографии или только по этимологии (наиболее популярные метки), это сделает сообщество неинтересным для тех, кто данным разделом языкознания не интересуется.

Но как с этим бороться? Правил ведь такие вопросы не нарушают.
 Во-первых; сами пользователи могут голосовать за закрытие вопроса и если таковых наберётся 5 человек, вмешательство модератора и не понадобится.
Во-вторых; при наличии спорных моментов модераторы имет право закрывать подобные вопросы.
В-третьих; Если эти вопросы исходят от одного пользователя, модераторы могут с ним связаться для уточнения причины массовых вопросов на одну тему и при необходимости даже ограничить этому пользователю доступ к сообществу.

По поводу третьего пункта имеет смысл внести изменения в правила сообщества. Добавив пункт с примерно таким содержанием:

> Не допускается засорение главной страницы однотипными вопросами, заданными через короткий промежуток времени. Например, сперва задать "Как пишется **жи-ши**?", а через минуту -  "Как пишется **ча-ща**?", и сразу после этого - "Как пишется **чу-щу**?". Если у вас накопилось несколько вопросов на одну тему постарайтесь их сформулировать в одном, или задавайте через более-менее длительные промежутки времени. Очень вероятно, что после ответа на ваш первый вопрос, отпадёт необходимость во втором.

Answer (score 0):

Вопросы типа «Как называется вещь» нормальны, они про русский язык. И русским же могли и задаваться, т. е. формулироваться со всеми сопутствующими вербальными трудностями. Вопросы, не требующие таких усилий — «Что-это-на-картинке?», — своей лёгкостью провоцирует авторов на иллюстрирование, безудержное и некачественное. О метке Название: она выросла над собой от Прорехи как дыры до Старого Арбата! На неё пора вводить мораторий. Согласен, что «вряд ли кто-нибудь из Сети придет к нам за этим кронштейном».

Вывод. Иллюстрировать дозволять только отвечающим, опцию в теле вопроса убрать. Подобрать подходящую метку.